# iOS: update object of NSMutableArray in for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I need to update / add a key -> value pair in a NSMutableArray.

I would like to add a key with a fix value if the key isn't set already.

I tried the following - but the app is crashing at `addObject` with a "mutating method sent to immutable object" error:

```cs
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"bookmarks"];

    for (id bookmark in bookmarks) {

        if ([bookmark objectForKey:@"type"] == NULL){
            [bookmark addObject:@"old" forKey:@"type"];
        }
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: `bookmarks` is mutable but none of the arrays it contains are mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//SAVING

NSMutableArray *bookmarksSaving = [NSMutableArray new];

[bookmarksSaving addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"red"] forKeys:@[@"color"]]];
[bookmarksSaving addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"yellow"] forKeys:@[@"color"]]];
[bookmarksSaving addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"green",@"new"] forKeys:@[@"color",@"type"]]];

[defaults setObject:bookmarksSaving forKey:@"bookmarks"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//MODIFY

NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"bookmarks"];

NSUInteger index = 0;
for (NSDictionary *bookmark in bookmarks) {

    NSMutableDictionary *bookmarkMutable = [bookmark mutableCopy];

    if ([bookmarkMutable objectForKey:@"type"] == nil)
    {
        [bookmarkMutable setValue:@"old" forKey:@"type"];
        [bookmarks replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:bookmarkMutable];
    }

    index++;
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

You have to save your bookmarks as `NSMutableDictionary` to be able to add/remove keys/value

Comment: my values are saved in a NSMutableDicionary: NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:titel, @"titel", code, @"code", @"liga", @"type", nil];
    
    [dataArray addObject:dict];

Comment: This is not going to work. Objects saved to user defaults are immutable so you need to make a mutableCopy of the dictionary. You are also modifying but not pushing it back to the array, and not pushing the modified array back to userDefaults so there's a lot missing there.

Comment: @Rog okay, so the best way is to create a new NSMutableArray with the updated values and override the userDefaults?

Comment: @JacopoPenzo I tried it already, but the app is crashing with this error: [__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

Answer (score 1):

Your outer array contains immutable dictionaries. One option would be the following:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"bookmarks"];

[booksmarks enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *bookmark, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if (!bookmark[@"type"]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mutable = [bookmark mutableCopy];
        mutable[@"type"] = @"old";
        [bookmarks replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[mutable copy]];
    }
}];

// Update NSUserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"bookmarks"];
```

This should be nice an efficient since it can update multiple dictionaries concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSArray *bookmarks = [defaults objectForKey:@"bookmarks"];
  NSMutableArray *newBookMarks = [bookmarks mutableCopy];
  for (NSDictionary *bookmark in bookmarks) {
    NSMutableDictionary *newBookmark = [bookmark mutableCopy];
    if (![bookmark objectForKey:@"type"]){
      [newBookmark setObject:@"old" forKey:@"type"];
    }
    [newBookMarks addObject:newBookmark];
  }
  [defaults setObject:newBookMarks forKey:@"bookmarks"];
  [defaults synchronize];
```